# 'Gauge invariant phase' - KG equation with EM potential in Hawking radiation

Tags: general-relativity, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Given the massless scalar electromagnetism equation
$$g^{ab}(\nabla_a -ie A_a)(\nabla_b -ie A_b)\phi=0,    \quad \quad \quad \quad(3.5)$$
I include the following passage from Hawking's "Particle creation by black holes".

[image]

I've shown that $k^a$ is null wherever the WKB approx is valid and have derived (3.6), but I'm not sure what is actually referred to as the "gauge invariant phase"(GIP) difference? It seems as if this should be a scalar, since $z^a$ "connects points with GIP difference $ik_a z^a$", a scalar!

I was thinking along the lines of taylor expanding $k^a$ around a point $p$ in the direction of $z^a$: $k^a(p) \approx k^a(p) + z^b \partial_b k^a|p$ but this doesn't seem to help...

The final statement I take to mean that $k^b\nabla_b(k_a z^a)=0$, which one can prove using (3.6-3.7).

Comment: It is not the *phase* that is gauge invariant it is *phase difference*.

Comment: Are you saying that the difference in *actual* phase of the solution at neighboring points is gauge invariant (not some otherwise defined phase)? Why is it given by $z_a k^a$ ?

Comment: My point was a purely grammatical: instead of looking for the meaning of term GIP you should look for the meaning of GIPD because nowhere in the text it is suggested that GIP is a thing.